# Howto configureedit++ as system text editor for ipython's magicCommand %edit

Tags: ipython, notepad++

In **ipython** the magic-command %edit opens the default text editor on microsoft windows. On window-7 this is notepad, a robust, but somewhat limited text editor.

I'd like to have started **notedpad++** my favorite editor for scripting. I changed already the association of py/txt/ etc. files to notedpad++. Thus doubleclicking such files works well. Anyhow in ipython **%edit** still starts the notepad.exe.

Is there a way to change this configuration of ipython?

regards 
olippuner

Comment: Try setting a system variable `EDITOR` pointing to the location of the notepad++ executable. You can also control the editor by setting TerminalInteractiveShell.editor in ipython_config.py

Answer (score 0):

The `%edit` command will invoke the editor set in your environment as `EDITOR`. If this variable is not set, it will default to notepad under Windows.

You can also control the editor by setting TerminalInteractiveShell.editor in ipython_config.py.

Source: [IPython documentation](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/config/editors.html)